# Joomla doesn't work with PDO connection

Tags: php, joomla, pdo

Hey guys I need your help I have this code in a localhost file :

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');

$data = array();

$results = $db->query("SELECT * from YOUR_TABLE_NAME");
while ($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $data[$row['prov_name']][] = $row;
}
```

But when I try to integrate this file in Joomla it doesn't work! Do you know how can I "transform" this into Joomla connection?

I always use this one for some select

```
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = 'SELECT CA_id FROM compras_activos where STAT_name = "Solicitado"';
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->loadObjectList();
    $CA_id = $result[0];
```

But that is just for one specific value but now I need all(*) the table.
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the Joomla Documentation for database queries? Everything you need is there: http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Comment: So why can't you just change the query in the second example you've provided?

Comment: Simply change `CA_id` to `*` but as mentioned before, please read the documentation as this is the old method for writing a database query

Comment: @Lodder can you help me with that ? I need to transform it into select in joomla and I replace PDO::FETCH_ASSOC with..? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should really read the [documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase) that I provided. If you are able to write a query as shown in your question, then this should not be too taxing. You can use the following:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();    
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName('*'))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__compras_activos'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('STAT_name') . ' = '. $db->quote('Solicitado')); 
$db->setQuery($query);

$result = $db->loadObjectList();
```

If your database table do not belong to an extension associated with Joomla, then remove the `#__` prefix in the above code.

Hope this helps